# Using a string resource to name (label) a widget's BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, widget, broadcastreceiver, label, android-widget

I've a widget defined as follows:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Label = "Upcoming")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" })]
[MetaData("android.appwidget.provider", Resource = "@xml/widget_daily")]
public class Widget_Daily : AppWidgetProvider
{
...
}
```

What I'm after is to localise the "Label" associated with the BroadcastReceiver, referencing the **Resource.String.widget_title_upcoming** string resource.

As a side-question, once this is managed, what happens to a user's Upcoming widget if 1) they already had it on their home screen and 2) its Label has been changed as their phone's language is set to a supported non-English language. Will it continue to operate as before? Or does it need to be re-inserted for it to function correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Label = "@string/Upcoming")]
```